# Rendering Clear Glass with Shadow Catcher and Transparent Background (Glass looks white instead of clear)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, glass, shadowcatcher

This is the coffee cup that I made and it is rendered with the cycles engine on top of a white plane:
[image]

This is the coffee cup that I made and it is rendered with the cycles engine on top of a white plane acting as a shadow catcher. AKA for the plane I selected "Object Properties" > "Visibility" > then checked the box "Shadow Catcher". I also checked the box labeled "transparent" under "film" in the "Render Properties" tab:
[image]

I am trying to composite this cup into a video (using davinci resolve) so I need the background to be transparent but the cup just ends up looking white instead of clear. Is there a way to make the cup have a shadow while still being mostly transparent?

Btw, I'm using Blender 2.83.5

Comment: Did you render/save the alpha channel?

Comment: How would I do that? Is there a way to export/save the alpha channel separately? The only place in this file that I see "alpha" listed is here in my composite node. https://imgur.com/dQBKG76

Comment: What format are you using to export the image? Try EXR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: GUI Setting]
Under "Film" also check "Transparent Glass"
You must use a Glass Shader on your glass, adding a Gloss Shader mixing a with Fresnel works, too.

[image: Full Render]

It is possible to save the alpha channel separately.
[image: The alpha channel]